# Set focus to component #2 input field after setting component #1 input field value in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

ReactJS newbie question. I'm trying to set focus to the "Emergency Service" input field after setting current location on the "Location Lookup" field but both fields live in separate components. I'm already making use of useRef in each component but trying to reference either ref from another component returns an error. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Please see my project at link below. I added a comment on line 208 of LocationLookup.js where I'm trying to trigger focus to the Emergency Service field.  https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-waterfall-3okx4?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick solution would be:

1. Change EmergencyService - wrap it with React.forwardRef, pass ref to Input (also see how to combine refs (for example https://github.com/gregberge/react-merge-refs)
2. Create ref (emergencyServiceRef) by useRef() in SearchBar and pass it to EmergencyService.
3. Pass prop to LocationLookup (maybe onLocationChange)
4. on line 208, call onLocationChange()
5. In SearchBar, you would handle callback onLocationChange and do "emergencyServiceRef.current.focus()

Comment: Thanks a bunch for sharing this. I wasn't aware of react-merge-refs. Will definitely give this a try.

Comment: It simplyfies managing refs, but you can write your own function to combine refs - used when you must handle ref from forwardRef and you also have ref inside component.

The goal is to handle location change and focus - both in parent component.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like I will be able to use mergeRefs on the component since it returns "function components cannot be given refs".

Comment: Yes, that is why you should wrap EmergencyService with forwardRef ... EmergencyService = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => { code }) ... SearchBar would look like this: "<EmergencyService ref={emergencyServiceRef} className={classes.fieldSeperator} />" ... Inside EmergencyServide: <EmergencyServiceTextField inputRef={mergeRefs([emergencyServiceField, ref])} ...>

Comment: My first attempt was to wrap EmergencyService with forwardRef in SearchBar.js, such as "const EmergencyServiceField = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {    
     return <EmergencyService ref={ref} {...props}/>
  });" but this is what returned the error. If you're saying I need to wrap the code in EmergencyService.js do I wrap just the code inside of the return, the entire code in the export function, or the entire code in the component which includes styles, etc. ? Sorry for my confusion, just trying to get a grip on this.

Comment: Thanks again! I was finally able to get this working using your examples above.